# What does "ground by hand" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> It's a spyglass, a.k.a a primitive handheld telescope. This six-inch-long gadget looks like a prop for  steampunk cosplay: tortoiseshell sides, brass fittings, lenses **ground by hand**.
>
> Gray, C. (2015) *Ten Thousand Skies Above You*. HarperTeen

What does "ground by hand" mean? I couldn't find any reasonable meaning of "ground" may fit here.

Remarks: I do not think one can resolve this question by a dictionary, by himself. To resolve it, one needs to know "ground" is the participle form of the word "grind", but not the infinitive form of the word "ground". And to know that, one needs to understand **ground by hand** is a past participle phrase. As English learners who haven't learned these knowledge yet, how could one resolves it by a dictionary, by themself.

Comment: I think your edit is unlikely to reopen the question. If you search for ground in a dictionary, and look at the definitions where it's used as a verb, you can see four definitions. 1. past simple and past participle of grind   2. If aircraft are grounded, they are prevented from flying or ordered not to fly.  3. to forbid (= refuse to allow) a child or young person from going out as a punishment   4. to connect a piece of electrical equipment to the ground with a wire (I used Cambridge Dictionary here).

Comment: And if you know what "lenses" means, if you don't, check a dictionary, you'll know that the most appropriate definition is number 1, the past simple and past participle of **grind**. And then? Ha, just kidding, there is no more **and then** - you get your solution! If you grind lenses by hand, you get lenses ground by hand. So can't this be solved by a dictionary? You just need to check up one word! Just one!

Comment: Ha, I told you that you can't reopen it.

Comment: You are right. I didn't find the entry which tells "ground" could be the past participle of "grind",  as too many entries in my dictionary. Thank you for explaining 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a lens, you start with a flat piece of glass and you grind away the glass you don't want, to make a curved surface.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpKInEL9vO0) of someone grinding a lens by hand.

"Ground" is the past participle of "grind", so If you grind a lens by hand, you will get a lens (that is) ground by hand.